# Panic report for Macbook Pro (retina 15-inch late 2013) macOS Mojave 10.14.6

Tags: mojave, error

I'm getting the black screen error which leads to a computer reset. Is there anyone here that could help please? Running Macbook Pro (retina 15-inch late 2013) on macOS Mojave 10.14.6. Here is the panic report:

```
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff800a1cdbff): "thread_invoke: preemption_level -1, possible cause: unlocking an unlocked mutex or spinlock"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-4903.278.28/osfmk/kern/sched_prim.c:2420

Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address

0xffffff913cdcb8e0 : 0xffffff800a1af58d 

0xffffff913cdcb930 : 0xffffff800a2eb145 

0xffffff913cdcb970 : 0xffffff800a2dc87a 

0xffffff913cdcb9e0 : 0xffffff800a15c9d0 

0xffffff913cdcba00 : 0xffffff800a1aefa7 

0xffffff913cdcbb20 : 0xffffff800a1aedf3 

0xffffff913cdcbb90 : 0xffffff800a1cdbff 

0xffffff913cdcbc10 : 0xffffff800a1cc17f 

0xffffff913cdcbc60 : 0xffffff800a2d4889 

0xffffff913cdcbcb0 : 0xffffff800a2d3f98 

0xffffff913cdcbce0 : 0xffffff800a8839bd 

0xffffff913cdcbd10 : 0xffffff800a290db0 

0xffffff913cdcbd40 : 0xffffff800a291b0b 

0xffffff913cdcbd80 : 0xffffff800a1b4dcc 

0xffffff913cdcbdd0 : 0xffffff800a18fb41 

0xffffff913cdcbe50 : 0xffffff800a1a425e 

0xffffff913cdcbef0 : 0xffffff800a2c27b7 

0xffffff913cdcbfa0 : 0xffffff800a15d1b6 



BSD process name corresponding to current thread: WacomTouchDriver



Mac OS version:

18G4032



Kernel version:

Darwin Kernel Version 18.7.0: Mon Feb 10 21:08:45 PST 2020; root:xnu-4903.278.28~1/RELEASE_X86_64

Kernel UUID: A52CF11D-A733-3E77-832B-D42063739C84

Kernel slide:     0x0000000009e00000

Kernel text base: 0xffffff800a000000

__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8009f00000

System model name: MacBookPro11,2 (Mac-3CBD00234E554E41)



EOF

Model: MacBookPro11,2, BootROM 159.0.0.0.0, 4 processors, Intel Core i7, 2 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.18f15

Graphics: kHW_IntelIrisProItem, Intel Iris Pro, spdisplays_builtin

Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020

Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1600 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x484D54343531533641465238412D50422020

AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x134), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.77.61.3 AirPortDriverBrcmNIC-1305.9)

Bluetooth: Version 6.0.14d6, 3 services, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports

Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0

Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256F, 251 GB

USB Device: USB 3.0 Bus

USB Device: Apple Internal Keyboard / Trackpad

USB Device: BRCM20702 Hub

USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller

USB Device: Intuos PTM

USB Device: Generic USB Hub

USB Device: AirPod Case

USB Device: Hub

USB Device: Apple Cinema Display

USB Device: My Book 111D

Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 17.1
```

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here with macOS 10.12.6 (16G2136) Sierra. The culprit is Wacom driver. Update it or report to Wacom to fix it if already updated.

Comment: Thank you, we arrived at the same conclusion.